# Get the most recent row for each order ID, after a join?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join

I have 2 tables:

`sms_send` has following columns:
`created_at, order_id, sms_id, mobile, msg`

`sms_msg` has following columns `id, short_desc`.

`sms_id` corresponds to `id` in `sms_msg`.

`sms_send` can have multiple rows with the same `order_id`, but `sms_id` may (not) be same for each of the records.

`sms_msg` will have only unique `id`s.

I want to join the two tables (only rows created after July 1 2013, using the following info:

For each `order_id`, get the `sms_id` and join the `short_desc` from the other table, but return only the most recent record.

So, I'll have most recent records for each `order_id` with corresponding `short_desc` joined.

Here's my attempt:

```
SELECT
    *,
    `sms_msg`.`short_desc`
FROM 
    `sms_send`
INNER JOIN
    `sms_msg`
ON
    `sms_send`.`sms_id` = `sms_msg`.`id`
WHERE
    `created_at` > '2013-07-01 00:00:00'
HAVING 
    `created_at` = (SELECT `created_at` FROM `sms_msg` GROUP BY `id` HAVING `created_at` = MAX(`created_at`))
```

This does not work, and the subquery returns multiple rows.

Why so? And how do I fix it?

Comment: You don't need `HAVING` if you don't use `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

If `created_at` is unique for a given order_id, and is type DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, or a character format in canonical format, then this will return the specified result set.

```
SELECT s.created_at
     , s.order_id
     , s.sms_id
     , s.mobile
     , s.msg
     , t.short_desc
  FROM (
         SELECT m.order_id
              , MAX(m.created_at) AS latest_created_at
           FROM sms_send m
          WHERE m.created_at >= '2013=07-01' 
          GROUP
             BY m.order_id
       ) l
  JOIN sms_send s
    ON s.order_id = l.order_id
   AND s.created_at = l.latest_created_at
  JOIN sms_msg t
    ON t.id = s.sms_id
```